# Java 9, Jigsaw and automatic modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Java 9 / 10. I have been struggling with a simple project for more than a week.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to use commons-collections as an automatic module (I have tried to add it with maven but that did not work out well).

So, I have red that I need to put the jar onto the module-path. Where does IntelliJ take this modulepath from? How can I tell the IDE to add commons-collections into the project so that
1. the compiler can find it at compile time and
2. Maven can find it at build time?

Anyone can help?

EDIT:
I have tried to add it in the project-structure dialog as a module dependency in all kinds of different combinations. I have literally tried hundreds of things, moved the jar around in the structure and I cannot find a simple enough doc to tell me how to do this.
I have used compiler options to add "--module-path automatic" (module specific and general compile options) in order to make IDEA find the thing and let Java make an automatic module out of it.

Comment: Well "--module-path automatic" sounds incorrect, it might better have been `--module-path <path to your .jar file>`. On another note, specifying the dependency in maven should've worked as well, if you could elaborate on what didn't work there would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a library entry first, to make it available under `Modules`:

Step 1: Add a library (Add -> Java -> jar file)

[image]

Step 2: Select the module (remember to click "Apply")

[image]

After that, the `module-info.java` file will be successfully validated:

[image]

Comment: Might suggest OP to cross verify their intelliJ version as well :)

Comment: IDEA Version: 2018.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Intellij uses a module path if you run a program from an (intellij) module containing module-info.java, otherwise it will use a classpath.

I tried importing common4 as a module, it does seem to work for me, but I had to use a different 'requires' argument as compared to yours. Your 'requires' is 'commons.collections4', mine is 'org.apache.commons.collections4' (check the commons4  manifest entry for the highlighted Automatic-Module-Name and use that instead).

[image: commons4 module]

If the Automatic-Module-Name is missing from the commons4 manifest (it is absent from version 4.1 and earlier), Java may not detect the jar as a module if the name contains digits or illegal characters. Some maven repository jars therefore will not work and intelli will not see those jars as modules.

[image]

You can also check for a bad filename by using the following command:

```
jar --file=/path/to/jar --describe-module
```

If the command fails, it's likely that the jar does not have an Automatic-Module-Name entry and that the filename is poorly named.

ok

`jar --file=C:\temp\jigsaw1-1.0.jar --describe-module`

bad

`jar --file=C:\temp\jigsaw1.0.jar` --describe-module`

'jigsaw1.0: Invalid module name: '0' is not a Java identifier'

Some maven jars may therefore fail to be detected as modules as they tend to look similar.

Comment: A call from Peter is a nice touch.